# Using a spinner as a menu - binary selection

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a spinner control to allow my user to select a radio station but (for reasons of limited screen space) am also trying to use the SAME control to mute/unmute and switch off. I want to change the formatting of the selected station when the user selects MUTE (and also recaption MUTE to UNMUTE) and reverts it to normal when they select UNMUTE or select the station again.

My problem is that if I select MUTE, whilst I can reformat the text to show the muted station, the spinner control thinks that the selected index is that of the MUTE/UNMUTE entry and thus selecting UNMUTE doesn’t fire the event because there doesn't appear to have been a change. How to I catch selection of UNMUTE?

```
private RadioArrayAdapter adapter;
private CharSequence mSelectedFrequency = "Radio 4";
private SceneFragmentListener mListener;

public interface SceneFragmentListener{
    void onRadioSet(StringSetting);
}

//Spinner populated when the fragment is set up in onCreateView()

spnRadio.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView t = (TextView) view;
        String s = t.getText();

        if ("OFF".equals(s)) {
            adapter.setSelection(position); //This just causes the selected item to be highlighted
            t.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRadioOff));
            t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags()&(~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
            mSelectedFrequency = "OFF";
            mListener.onRadioSet("OFF");

        } else if "MUTE".equals(s) {
            t.setText(mSelectedFrequency);
            t.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRadioMute));
            t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags()|Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            mRadioFreqs.set(0,"UNMUTE");
            mListener.onRadioSet("MUTE");

        } else if "UNMUTE".equals(s) {
            t.setText(mSelectedFrequency);
            t.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRadioOn));
            t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags()&(~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
            mRadioFreqs.set(0,"MUTE");
            mListener.onRadioSet("UNMUTE");

        } else {
            adapter.setSelection(position);
            t.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRadioOn));
            t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags()&(~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
            mSelectedFrequency = s;
            mListener.onRadioSet(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried sticking in a boolean blocker and recursively calling onItemSelected() within mute and unmute if blocks but it looks to me like the selection isn't actually made until my code completes so this has no effect.

Thanks for looking...

Comment: Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Pretty please with flowers?